# SSH lets me login with a password even though I set "PasswordAuthentication no"

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I'm trying to turn off password authentication for SSH after setting up public key access. I have these set in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

However, it still lets me login with a password.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to restart sshd, so it wasn't using the new settings. This fixed it:

```
/etc/rc.d/sshd restart
```